# Manually Reorder Objects

Tags: objects

I would like to manually reorder the objects

[image]

It should be:

Obj_1

Obj_2

Obj_3

... but I cannot get those items to change order using straight drag&drop.

I did notice that the orders were initially based on the order in which the items were placed.

I have turned off Sort Alphabetically

Currently using Blender version 3.0.0

Comment: so it looks like you want to sort them out alphabetically?

Comment: You could linked-duplicate Obj_2, then Obj_3, delete the originals, and rename the dupes to the original names.

Comment: @moonboots  On the contrary ,I want to sort them manually.

Comment: @scurest That's a way too, but I think Marty Fouts' way is better.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very unpleasant limitation in the Outliner, and there has been discussions about it with the developers, but as of now, the best way to reorganize is, assuming that you have disabled alphabetical sort, as you have:

1. Move all of the object *out* of the collection.  You can do this by selecting them all and moving them to a different collection or to the top level *Scene Collection*
2. Move them back in one at a time.  Add the one you want on the bottom of the list *first* and work backwards.

Obviously you can optimize this by leaving objects you want near the end in the collection, but the basic rule is *newly added objects go at the head of the list.*

Comment: Okay.That help me a lot!
By the way, how to solve the sorting of bones?

Comment: Like this[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H35YNmh7XNZKtSNKfNUGRyUAWpAOEiYg/view?usp=sharing)